# Why in JS without -1 i get undefined on the second for loop in the console

Tags: javascript, loops, undefined, decrement

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    console.log(numbers[i]);
}
for (let i = numbers.length; i >= 0; i--) { 
    console.log(numbers[i]);
}
```

What if "let i = numbers.length;" is not decremented by "- 1" I get undefined in console.log and with - 1 it doesn't yield undefined firstly?

Therefore in the end I get another undefined?

Comment: Because numbers[6] is not initialized. Arrays start at zero, as your first loop demonstrates.

Comment: becase you are staring at numbers.length, when it should be numbers.length -1

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović and just to add to that - conversely, the *last* item in the array is at index `length - 1`.

Comment: Array index starts with 0 and ends with numbers.length-1

Comment: Thanks @Selvam M, that clears up why it yields undefined when there is no -1 on numbers.length

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    console.log(numbers[i]);
}
for (let i = numbers.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    console.log(numbers[i]);
}
```

As Above